# GDI Handles in Windows Service vs Interactive Application

Tags: winforms, windows-services, gdi+, window-handles

I have a code that is used in an Winforms application. The same code is also used in a Windows Service (exe running as Windows Service). The code grabs the handles to ICONs. But what I found is that, in Task Mangaer (and GDI View), when I ran the Winforms Application the app shows the GDI count. But when I ran the code via Windows Service, the service instance in Task Manager isn't showing any count for GDI. So, does this mean that Windows Service can never hold a GDI handle? If so, how does the code work, that is how is the code that runs on the handle actually working in Windows Service.

Comment: Task Manager can't retrieve the GDI count for processes in another session, so it shows it as zero.

Comment: What do you mean by another session? Service is also running with my credentials.

Comment: Every process in Windows runs in a particular "Remote Desktop session", aka "Terminal Services session", sometimes just called "session" although that can be ambiguous.  See the "Session ID" column in Task Manager.  If two different users are logged in at the same time, they are in different sessions, and you'll find that each user can see the GDI count for their own processes but not those of the other user.  (In Windows 10, you need to run Task Manager "as administrator" to see other user's processes.)

Comment: In particular, all services run in session zero.  Google "session zero isolation" for more information.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, that's the issue. I wrote a service to capture the GDI handle count and I could now see the count for the window service as well as both are running in s session 0. Can you submit the answer so that I can accept the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services are in fact able to create and use GDI handles in exactly the same way as an ordinary application, except that the display surfaces are not visible to the user.

However, Task Manager is only able to query this information for processes that [are in the same session](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/07/24/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations/) that it is running in, and [services always run in a separate session.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/)

So, basically, just a false alarm. :-)

Comment: But, is there a way to see the GDI objects of an application started as service?

Comment: @IspasClaudiu, it's complicated, but the short answer is no.  If you want a display surface to be visible, run the code in the user's session, not as a service.